# how to unsubscribe from an observable returned from Observable.create in rxjs 5.1

Tags: rxjs

I have this code:

```
async download(fileToUpload: UploadedFileMetaData): Promise<Observable<DownloadEvent>> {
    const url = await this.getDownloadUrl(fileToUpload);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      console.log(observer);
      xhr.open('GET', url);

      xhr.send();

      xhr.addEventListener('progress', (progress) => {
        let percentCompleted;
```

That returns an ovservable.

I then use it like this:

```
const downloadSubscription = await this.blobStorageService.download(file);

downloadSubscription.subscribe((event) => // do stuff
```

Multiples of these might be created.

How do I unsubscribe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with this:

```
   const destroy$ = new Subject<boolean>();

   downloadSubscription.takeUntil(destroy$).subscribe(
      // main body
      },
      (downloadEvent: FailureDownloadEvent) => {
        // error
        destroy$.next(true);
        destroy$.unsubscribe();
      },
      () => {
        // cleanup
        destroy$.next(true);
        destroy$.unsubscribe();
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `subscribe()` method return value which is a `Subscriber` object in a variable and call the `unsubscribe()` method when you want to unsubscribe.

```
const downloadSub = downloadSubscription.subscribe((event) => {});

downloadSub.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: By convention observables get the `$` suffix, not subscriptions.

Comment: Yeah, I made that mistake. I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: my code is subscribing to async events raised from xhr.   I want to unsubscribe when the xhr has finished.  The xhr finishes in the Observable.create callback.  I'm not sure how to unsubscribe in this scenario